# How to create a recursive mysql query to return a document hierarchy?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a mysql query to traverse UP a modx document tree to return:

- an array of document ids
- the top "N" document

Each modx document resource has a field for "parent" id, so I need to feed it a child resource id and an integer representing the number of resources from the TOP of the tree I want to pull the id from. i.e. if I fed it;

childid = 22, top resource = 3, I would expect the result set to be:

```
----------------------------------------
|top|        parents                   |
----------------------------------------
| 5 | 1,2,5,6,7,8,etc                  |
----------------------------------------
```

I started trying to write a proceedure, but am not having much luck with it sot far: [i.e. this example does not work at all]

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getParentArray;

CREATE PROCEDURE getParentArray(childid);

BEGIN

DECLARE parent INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

WHILE parent != 0 DO

    SELECT `parent` AS `parentid` 
    FROM `modx_site_content` WHERE `id` = childid;

    SET parent = parentid;

    # somehow create a list of parents here? 

END WHILE;

END

CALL getParentArray(7055);
```

What is the best way to approach this? Am I even on the right track?

Comment: probably not a great idea (at very least for clarity) to declare a variable with the exact same name as the main field you are concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL doesn't really support arrays, your best bet is either:

(1) string concatenation to form a csv string, or

(2) create a temporary table within the stored procedure, insert your findings, and then `select *` the temp table at the end of the procedure to have it return it as a result set. (Don't forget to drop the temp table after the select, you never know how long a future client that could call it might keep it's connection active.)

Comment: String concatenation, yes, technically I may not need the array. but creating tables is going to be pretty memory/processor expensive - I could wind up iterating over this proc 1000's of times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I wound up doing:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getParentArray;

CREATE PROCEDURE getParentArray(IN cid INT, IN target INT)

BEGIN

    DECLARE pid INT;
    DECLARE parent_id_array VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE my_parent VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';

    REPEAT

        SET pid = (SELECT `sc`.`parent` FROM `modx_site_content` `sc` WHERE `id` = cid);

        SET parent_id_array = CONCAT(pid,',',parent_id_array);

        SET cid = pid;

    UNTIL cid = 0 END REPEAT;

    SET my_parent = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX((SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(parent_id_array, ',', target)), ',', -1));

    IF my_parent = '' 

        THEN SET my_parent = -1; 

    END IF;

    SELECT parent_id_array , target , my_parent;

END;

CALL getParentArray(6224, 3);
```